# AEM as IDP( Identity Provider) for CRM using SAML

Tags: osgi, single-sign-on, saml, aem

Is there any out of the box implementation to act AEM as IDP for another application by SAML. I have googled about this and found there is OOTB configuration for AEM to act as a service provider (SP). Please provide informtion or references to make AEM as IDPso that the users in the AEM are authorised to use some other service provider by using single sign on (SSO). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, AEM (at least as of AEM version 6.2) can only play the Service Provider (SP) role in a federation supporting the SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO profile.

You would need to deploy one of the supported SAML 2.0 IdP in order to implement seamless cross domain browsing for your users.

Answer (score 0):

AEM does not expose any functionality of an IDP so using it for this purpose won't work. A custom implementation or 3rd party libraries might be able to expose this feature but there is nothing OOTB to provide it.